# How can I access a parent DOM from an iframe on a different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I have a website and my domain is registered through [Network Solutions](http://networksolutions.com/) (who I would **not** recommend). I'm using their Web Forwarding feature which allows me to "mask" my domain so that when a user visits http://lucasmccoy.com they are actually seeing http://lucasmccoy.comlu.com/ through an HTML frame. The advantages of this are that the address bar still shows `http://lucasmccoy.com/`.

The disadvantages are that I cannot directly edit the HTML page in which the frame is owned. For example, I cannot change the page title or favicon. I have tried doing it like so:

```
$(function() {
    parent.document.title = 'Lucas McCoy';
});
```

But of course this gives me a JavaScript error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://lucasmccoy.com/ from frame with URL http://lucasmccoy.comlu.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains) attempting to do the same thing except the OP has access to the other pages HTML whereas I do not.

Is there anyway in JavaScript/jQuery to make a cross-domain request to the DOM when you don't have access to that domain? Or is this something browsers just will not let happen for security reasons.

Comment: You may check this article http://madskristensen.net/post/Iframe-cross-domain-JavaScript-calls.aspx. It's forbidden because security reasons but if you really have to do it there are some workarounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Most browsers implement the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.