# Cross Domain Javascript calls using iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-domain

I want to have cross domain javascript call.

1: SiteA: www.sub1.foo.com

2: Open SiteB: www.bar.com in iframe from SiteA

3: Pass some value from SiteB to SiteA via javascript after some action in SiteB.

**Try 1:**
I followed this [article](http://madskristensen.net/post/Iframe-cross-domain-JavaScript-calls.aspx) and I followed #2 for my setup. But I keep getting errors:

IE: Invalid Argument

FF:Illegal document.domain value.

**Try 2:**
Followed this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb735305.aspx).

It works in FF. I can use window.parent.parent.MyFunction() but in IE I get "Permission Denied" error.

**Try 3:**
I even tried the window.postMessage technique but I am not even able to get that working.

Is anyone out there who has successfully implemented Cross Domain JS calls for situation like above.
Or any help / links / suggestions.

Comment: i tried for a long time and could never get it to work. I instead built a chrome extension which will allow any cross domain requests as long as you add the domains to the manifest...not sure if this will help you in your situation because the website visitors will not install an extension just to look at your website..

Comment: @Johnny: Nope that extension way won't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement window.postMessage to communicate accross iframes/windows across domains.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // What browsers support the window.postMessage call now?
        // IE8 does not allow postMessage across windows/tabs
        // FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5?), Opera10+

        function SendMessage()
        {
            var win = document.getElementById("ifrmChild").contentWindow;

            // http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/


            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072902/dom-exception-12-for-window-postmessage
            // Specify origin. Should be a domain or a wildcard "*"

            if (win == null || !window['postMessage'])
                alert("oh crap");
            else
                win.postMessage("hello", "*");
            //alert("lol");
        }



        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if (false) {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if (ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it ;)", event.origin);
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="ifrmChild" src="child.htm" frameborder="0" width="500" height="200" ></iframe>
    <br />


    <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="SendMessage();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Child.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        // Opera 9 supports document.postMessage() 
        // document is wrong
        window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
            //document.getElementById("test").textContent = ;
            alert(
                e.domain + " said: " + e.data
                );
        }, false);
        */

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
        // http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/
        // http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/
        // http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

        // .data – A string holding the message passed from the other window.
        // .domain (origin?) – The domain name of the window that sent the message.
        // .uri – The full URI for the window that sent the message.
        // .source – A reference to the window object of the window that sent the message.
        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if(false)
            {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else
            {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            //alert(evt.source.location.href)

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if(ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            // http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage
            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", evt.origin);
            evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", "*");
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body style="background-color: gray;">
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <textarea id="taRecvMessage" rows="20" cols="20" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had "Protocols, domains, and ports must match" error only on Safari, even though I postMessage to * target origin. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is restricted for security reasons.
It's been discussed previously on Stack Overflow here: [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Comment: I hoped there was some way because the second link workaround works with FF but not with IE.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this: http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/2006/10/22/resizing-iframes-across-domains/

some time ago :)