# Running javascript on an iframe with another domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a javascript function to validate user's input in input or textarea field, I also want to apply these functions on the Iframe's textarea.
Is it possible to run the parent's javascript on an iframe with another domain. If yes, how can I do it.
Sorry for my newbie question. Thanks in advance

Comment: is your iframe on the same domain?

Comment: post some code so that we can check

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Comment: abhitalks has already posted a link explaining the Same-Origin Policy. In some situations there are [some work-arounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/1169519) though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this as a result of the Same Origin Policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if the source of the iframe is on a different domain you won't be able to interact with the content.