# Iframe JS https->http parent window permissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I have an iframe that contains a https:// login page, and I have some JavaScript that applies CSS styles to the iframe on the parent window - this parent window being http://. The protocols don't match, and although I know this is to do with the cross domain issue, I can't figure out how it is possible to set both iframe and parent window to use the same protocol without affecting security.

Any help would be appreciated, and code can be posted if required.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's different scheme , you can't access it directly.

But it all depends on what you want to do :

You can use : `postMessage` ,  `hash period check` , create `cross proxy iframe` which has access to `parent.parent`

You can also use `window.name` ( but this will reload the other page).

You should tell us what you ACTUALLY want to do ( after you access the page)

Comment: Well the login iframe uses the jQuery validate plugin - the iframe on the parent window then adjusts to accommodate the validate notifications (e.g. Please Enter a Valid Email), so this is a simple .css() change.