# How to change css of parent iframe with jquery (on same domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I do not have much experience with Jquery and don't really know about Iframe and CSS combination on the main page.

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/x6ws7/4/ you can see there's a jquery script and some HTML, CSS and an iframe. I want to run the jquery when I click on an input field in the iframe and change the css of the parent (page?) of the iframe. For example, if I press on an input field (focus it), set display of the input field (or any other element) outside the iframe, to 'none' or so.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my Jquery at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('input').click(function(){
     $().changeStyle();
 });

 $.fn.changeStyle = function() {
     $(".outside").css({
         display: "none"
        });
 }
});
```

Comment: That's a cross domain iframe, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains

Comment: I guess that's right, but I'm working on the same domain name, which should make it possible, at least, that's what I have been told.

Comment: Maybe you would like to read this too : https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/protect-your-website-from-embedded-content-iframe-security

Comment: If same domain just access parent document using in iframe `parent.document`, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/p6Bf9/show/

Comment: I think the above code comes really close to the answer I seek, thank you very much. Can I see the code somehow, or rather an example with css changing code (or an alert box as simple example)?
Maybe something like this, but then with correct code?
http://jsfiddle.net/Lya6A/

Comment: I would like something like: http://jsfiddle.net/uP94Q/ but instead of the hide function on the first textbox, I want it on the second textbox (in the iframe), to change the css (set display to none) or any other css change. I have been told it should be possible to call the function from the main site into the iframe and from there, change the css of the main page.

Answer (score -1):

firstly you should assign the id or class  to your desire element let id of your desire input is cht so use bellow code

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        $("cht").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where "iframe" is declared, is that also where I can put any other class or id to change that css?

Comment: use firebug and get id of your desire element or add a class by jquery

Comment: What you described above here, doesn't it do the same thing as my code? I don't see any difference, or am I wrong?