# Redirect certain sites that are using an iframe to another URL

Tags: javascript, iframe

I was just wondering if this works anymore, I tried with the following script, and it does work at redirecting the iframe if they are not on the domain, however it doesn't allow the other domains, weeder and stumbleupon to access the content.

```
    window.onload = function(){
try
   {
     if (window.parent 
    && !(window.parent.location.hostname === "sitename.com" 
         || window.parent.location.hostname === "weeder.org"
         || window.parent.location.hostname === "stumbleupon.com"
         || window.parent.location.hostname === "localhost")){
          throw new Error();
       }
   }
   catch (e){
     window.location.href = "http://redirecttothis.com";
   }
}
```

It would be great if this could work as we are trying to stop iframe abusers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, modern browsers do now allow to do this. I think what you are looking for is not possible.

your can check the below url

[<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Comment: It works perfectly for the first domain, however it won't work for subsequent domains, so I'm guessing its not a problem that it doesn't work, I presume its more a problem with some aspect of the code.

Comment: can you try using var href = document.referrer; and then check the domain in href. Will that work ?