# Change background color of iframe with external href src?

Tags: html, css, iframe, background-color

Is it possible to load an external href src inside your iframe and then override the bg color of the external href src? Here's what I've tried:

```
<iframe src="https://www.externaldomain.com" style="background-color: #FFF !important;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an event with javascript or jquery. Something like this:

```
function changeBackground(color) {
   document.body.style.background = color;
}

<BODY onload="changeBackground('red');">
```

[change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Comment: that unfortunately does not change the bg color of the external href src that is loaded into the iframe. It only changes the bg of the document.

Comment: Chek this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains