# iframe unable to access its parent window properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

In the past, I can access properties and functions in parent window from an iframe, event the iframe is CORS. For example: `window.parent.api.func()`. However it stopped working in the most recent version of Chrome. When I reference the parent window properties, I got the following exception:

```
"Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8090" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)"
```

I understand from parent window to access iframe I need use postMessage. However it should be okay if access the parent window from iframe. Why it stopped working?

Comment: Found a related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains

Comment: Now I believe what I did in the past was using a reverse proxy to avoid the CORS problem. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

A different port counts as a different domain.  Either use postMessage like you said or make sure the ports match as well.  Also make sure you're not using the IP address of your computer for one and localhost for the other--it's gotta fully match.

Comment: is the CORS really the problem? I believe it used to be working. If indeed CORS (on different port) prevent access the parent window, I can try to get around it using a reverse proxy, but it is much easier without it, especially during development time.

Comment: you can change the hosts file on your machine and make them both match.  Put a host entry for `localhost:8090 somenewname.com` and `localhost:otherport somenewname.com`  Then use `somenewname.com` for both windows

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. But I don't think the hosts file can have port associated with it. It is just a dns name conversion.