# Is it possible to set style in cross domain iframe tag from within the iframe using jQuery or other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to set `style="width:100%"` in the iframe tag using jQuery or some other scripting language.

The script would reside in the content of the iframe which is on another domain.

Example:

```
<iframe src="domain 2" id="domain 1"></iframe>
```

The script on domain 2 inside the iframe page would style the tag of the iframe which is located on domain 1.

Is this possible with some kind of scripting language that can bypass security checks and origin policy?

More details: I have access to the content within the iframe and can control what is displayed in it. But I do not have access to the iframe tag, so I am not able to style it directly.

So I need to figure out how to do it from within the iframe. Setting body, html width 100% doesn't set the iframe in the parent page to 100%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Comment: It's not possible, and it shouldn't be. If it was possible with some trick, it would get fixed very fast because it'd be a gaping security hole. Documents in different domains can talk to each other, but only if both of them participate in it using `postMessage`. You can't access JS values or the DOM directly.

Comment: ok thanks just had to check your ideas.