# It's possible to remove controls from Google Maps with javascript without creating the function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwsy5vhu/ but imagine that we can't see the code. (Because it's not our site). We don't know the var X name that is using the map.

How we could hide controls using javascript? I.E: We open the browser inspector tool > console

And in the console what we could execute to hide controls?

I have tried:

```
map.setOptions({disableDefaultUI: true});
```

(And for some reason even using the real var name which is map it throws me an error that saying map isn't defined (?) )

Need a way to hide map controls without having access to the "source code", like just injecting a dynamic javascript code to target the existing map.

Maybe this is possible to do with CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! As it stands, your question is missing information. For example: Do you create the map yourself via the Google Maps API? Please update it according to [How do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`.setOptions`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setOptions) method on the `google.maps.Map` object which allows you to set the [`MapOptions`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions) dynamically:

```
var defaultUI = true;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('disableUI'), "click", function() {
   if (defaultUI) {
     map.setOptions({disableDefaultUI: true}); 
   } else {
     map.setOptions({disableDefaultUI: false}); 
   }
   defaultUI = !defaultUI;
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c18o5mnz/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -33,
      lng: 151
    },
    // disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  var defaultUI = true;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('disableUI'), "click", function() {
    if (defaultUI) {
      map.setOptions({
        disableDefaultUI: true
      });
    } else {
      map.setOptions({
        disableDefaultUI: false
      });
    }
    defaultUI = !defaultUI;
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="disableUI" value="disableUI" type="button" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @geocodezip. That's exactly what I was looking for. But what happens if we don't know the var x = new ... What happens if we don't know the var name to reference the x.setOptions....? It's possible to get the var name that is using x site? Thanks sir!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Is this not a question on code you wrote?  You didn't provide a [mcve] in your question, if this doesn't address your question, then your question will likely be closed as too broad or for not providing a MRE.

Comment: thanks forgot to edit the top message. I have edited my post. Hope now makes sense what I'm trying to do. Very appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you see the code?  Please provide the [mcve] **in your question itself** (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet), not (just) a link to an external site (like jsfiddle).

Comment: We can't see the code because it's not our site. I want to run this on an external website that has a map with controls. I'm using it in an iframe but want to remove the controls. I can't modify directly the map and that's why I'm trying to do it this way. This website allows me to run javascript / CSS but as the map it's pre-existent I can't modify the base-code of the map to add just a disableDefaultUI: true line. I can't add a minimal reproducible example because I don't know how to reproduce a similar scenario :(. Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to access the JavaScript cross domain in an iframe (if you don't control the code in that domain).  Related question: [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)