# capture input insde of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that is made to simulate normal bing :

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://bing.com/" name="myFrame"  style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0" ></iframe>
```

I want to capture input that goes throught it and log it to console. I tried to use this on javascript but it didn't worked.

```
const keyboard = document.querySelector('.keyboard');

keyboard.addEventListener('keydown', e =>{
    console.log('test')
})
```

Any ideas how can i solve this issue?

Comment: You're not allowed to execute javascript inside of an iframe if it's not from the same domain as your site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains

Comment: *"simulate normal bing"* that's a direct url to bing. Why would one simulate a site to an iframe and use a keylogger er listen for keystrokes? 

Comment: Hi, that was made to make an ilusion of bing and then, when i press ex. 9 to change my website back into ex. a game. I do not have any malicious intents.